# Mean and Standard Deviations of coefficient vectors using R?

Tags: r, simulation, mean, standard-deviation

How can I calculate the mean and standard deviation of each of the coefficients over the N=1000 MLR model fits using R?
Here's my function:

```
simfun <- function(a=56.25102409,b=1.78977412,c=0.08664925,n=18,x1.sd=18.87671,x2.sd=18.87671,e.sd=18.87671) {
   X1 <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=x1.sd)
   X2 <- rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=x2.sd) 
   e <-  rnorm(n, mean=0, sd=e.sd)
   Z <- a+b*X1+c*X2+e 
   data.frame(X1,X2,Z)
}

statfun <- function(samples) {
    coef(lm(Z~X1+X2,data=samples))
}

library(plyr)
raply(1000,statfun(simfun()))
```

Answer (score 0):

> res <- .Last.value

```
> apply(res,2,mean)
(Intercept)          X1          X2 
 57.9515278   1.6696702   0.1116194 
> apply(res,2,sd)
(Intercept)          X1          X2 
  2.5550134   0.3177064   0.2789701
```